# How to create range to html link

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create image link what scrolls down. This is not CRITICAL issue.

The image link works fine, but uses the whole HTML line, what I do not like. Below is my HTML code for that.

```html
<a href="#about">
  <div class="header-down-arrow">
    <span width="50px">
    <img src="downarrow.png" width="50px"></img>
    </span>
  </div>
</a>
```

Here is demonstration of my problem:

[image: Here]

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but try `display:inline-block` on `.header-down-arrow`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, need not to use close tag for `<img>`.

Set inline-block to the div `.header-down-arrow`

```css
.header-down-arrow {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<a href="#about">
  <div class="header-down-arrow">
    <span width="50px">
      <img src="downarrow.png" width="50px">
    </span>
  </div>
</a>
```